# Exporting map to PDF using PyQGIS freezes the CLI

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, export, pdf

When I try to export PDF using PyQGIS 3 API the CLI freezes when the execution reaches the `exporter.exportToPdf(pdf_fpath,exportSettings)` call, and no PDF is exported. even though I can export the PDF manually from the saved QGIS project.

Please find below the used source code:

```
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
        logging.info(f"layout exporter created ")
        exportSettings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()
        exportSettings.dpi=double(self.hum_event.default_pdf_res_dpi)
        qgs_project.write()
        logging.info(f"layout export dpi param setted -exporting to pdf ..{pdf_fpath}.")
        exporter.exportToPdf(pdf_fpath,exportSettings)
```